# Core Plot 2.1 fixed Y axis

Tags: ios, swift, core-plot

There are quite a few questions here on SO on how to fix an axis in CorePlot but all of them reference the `axisConstraints` property of the `CPTXYAxis` which is nonexistent in CorePlot 2.0 and later.

So the question is how to fix the Y axis in core plot 2.0 and newer?

I'm not doing anything fancy here:

```
let graph = CPTXYGraph(frame: self.nativeView.graphView.bounds)

let plotSpace = graph.defaultPlotSpace!
plotSpace.setPlotRange(CPTPlotRange(location: -1, length: 20), forCoordinate: .X)
plotSpace.setPlotRange(CPTPlotRange(location: -10, length: 20), forCoordinate: .Y)
plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = true
plotSpace.delegate = self

let axisSet = graph.axisSet
if let axis = axisSet?.axisForCoordinate(.Y, atIndex: 0) {
    axis.majorIntervalLength = 5
    axis.minorTicksPerInterval = 5

    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.positiveFormat = "#"
    formatter.negativeFormat = "#"
    axis.labelFormatter = formatter

    //Here I want to fix this thing..
}

//And then I create a scatter plot and add it and that's it
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `axisConstraints` property is part of the `CPTXYAxis` class. Casting the axis set to `CPTXYAxisSet` is the easiest way to do this in Swift:

```
let axisSet = graph.axisSet as! CPTXYAxisSet
let y = axisSet.yAxis
y.axisConstraints = CPTConstraints(lowerOffset: 0.0)
```

Comment: Holy jesus... the problem was me not casting it to `CPTXYAxisSet` so it was just `CPTAxisSet`... I feel so stupid right now. Thank you.